# Compare two columns in two different txt files windows

Tags: windows, powershell, text, cmd

I have two very large .txt files (~500k rows). I need to take two columns out of both files (by column names) and compare them against each other (similar to the way LEFT JOIN works in SQL). So I need to output to the third txt/csv file all combinations of values from two columns from the first file which do not exist in the second file.

I will need to automate this process, so I should be able to call it from command line. If anyone can point me to in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE**
The format of the files is exactly the same and the needed columns are never empty.

**Example**

First file

DataSource; Customer; City; Mapping; SugGroup
ARTS; John; London; Johny; LondonCustomers
ARTS; Chris; Munich; Jons; Germany
FEDS; Mary; London; James; Germany

Second file

DataSource; Customer; City; Mapping; SugGroup
ARTS; Chris; Munich; Jons; Germany
FEDS; Mary; London; James; Germany

What I need to do is to take two columns: Customer and Mappings. And find rows that are in the first file and not in the second one. So in the given example, the output file would look like:

Output file:

Customer; Mapping
John; Johny

Comment: Create a DB, add the strings to a table and execute LEFT JOIN? ;)

Comment: @duDE Already doing that. Due to the problem with the client's environment, it's very slow. So trying to come up with something else.

Comment: You could easily import the file with `Import-Csv` and select only the columns you need into `compare-Object`. That is of couse assuming your files are delimited otherwise you would have to manually delimit them. However 1 million rows of data in memory might be tough for powershell

Comment: You know that cmd is s-l-o-w by nature, of course. Perhaps it could be done - try giving us a small sample (just a few lines, preferably with headers.) Then prepare for other questions like what are the separators, how many unique combinations are there likely to be, are there empty columns, is this in fact fixed-column format? Do you want to be able to select the columns by name or is this resticted to known columns? And is the layout of the two files identical? Oh - and some examples of wht you want to do would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice against `Import-CSV`, as it doesn't work too well with files on the 100+ Mb range. Well, it works, but is dog slow.

Create a hash table. Read the second file row-by-row. Catenate the two columns and store the result in hashtable. Read the first file row-by-row and catenate its two columns to get similar a key. Check if the hashtable contains the same key. If it doesn't, save the data to the third file.

For a code example, please provide sample input and desired output.

#### Update:

You don't specify if it's possible to have same customer, mapping but change in other data. Assuming that's not the case, just calculate a hash for the whole row like so,

```
# Arraylist's initial size 500,000 elemnents
$secondFile = new-object Collections.ArrayList(500000)
# Init MD5 tools
$md5 = new-object Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = new-object Text.UTF8Encoding
# Read the 2nd large file
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText("c:\temp\secondFileBig.txt")
$i=0
while( ($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    # Get MD5 for each row and store it in the arraylist
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($line)))
    $secondFile.Add($hash) | out-null
    if(++$i % 25000 -eq 0) {write-host -nonewline "."}
}
$reader.Close()
# Sort the arraylist so that it can be binarysearched
$secondFile.Sort()
```

By using some dummy data about 500,000 rows, creating the hashes takes some 50 seconds on my computer. Now, let's read the other file and check line-by-line if it has same conent.

```
# Open and read the file row-vise
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText("c:\temp\firstFileBig.txt")

while( ($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    # Get MD5 for current row
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($line)))
    # If the row already exists in the other file, you'd find its MD5 index with
    # binarysearch in O(n log n) time. If found, you'd get zero or larger index        
    if($secondFile.BinarySearch($hash) -le -1) {
        "Not found: $line"
    }
}
$reader.Close()
```

Running the second part with dummy test data is way faster, as one can find out with `Measure-Command`. It is left as an exercise to the reader to figure out how to extract the relevant elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have added an example

Comment: thank you very much for the update. Really appreciate it. I will give it a go today and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again. Your suggestion was very helpful. Although unfortunately due to security restrictions in the client's environment I went down writing a small c# console application route.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=."
(
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=2,4delims=;" %%a IN (q26059159-2.txt) DO ECHO(%%a; %%b
)>q26059159-temp.txt
(
FOR /f "tokens=2,4delims=;" %%a IN (q26059159-1.txt) DO (
 ECHO(%%a; %%b|FINDSTR /v /x /g:q26059159-temp.txt>NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET "col1=%%a;%%b"
  ECHO(!col1:~1!
 )
)
)>q26059159-result.txt

TYPE q26059159-result.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used files named `q26059159-1.txt` and `q26059159-2.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Sadly, there are caveats to this code. Some could have been avoided with the provision of more information.

I asked for a data sample. Some artificial data was provided.

I asked what the separators are. I can derive that they're semicolons and each semicolon seems to be followed by a space. It seems that the data is not fixed-column.

I asked whether there were empty columns and received an evasive half-answer : " the needed columns are never empty"

I asked whether the columns required were fixed or were already known. Sadly, no response beyond an example which may be **the** requirement and may be **a** requirement - no information.

Ah - layout of the files is identical.

So why do I ask? For the sake of my health perhaps? Because it's the fashion? Insatiable curiosity like [The Elephant's Child](http://www.classicreader.com/book/899/1/) best beloved?

Simply - because it affects the approach.

For instance, the `for /f "tokens=...delims=..."` construct will neatly break text data into tokens. `delims` may be specified as many characters but the tokens are assigned by scanning the text line from the beginning and observing any delimiter *or sequence of delimiters* from the set.

The consequence is that if `;` is selected as a delimiter, each token=field will be assigned depending on the location of the `;` characters. If a field is empty, then the text may contain `;;` which will be seen as *one* delimiter, not two. That is why it is necessary to ask the question *are there empty columns*.

In this case, we have ";<kbd>Space</kbd>" separating columns. We can't select **both** `;` and <kbd>Space</kbd> since it's very likely that the data will contain spaces within the fields and that would be regarded as a column-delimiter so we couldn't simply column-count.

The consequence is that the data-columns appear to have a space prepended to them. All except the first one, just for convenience.

Next we look at the `tokens.` All very straight-forward. token-number = column-number.

Except...tokens is limited to 31. If you want column 44, then there are ways and means, but that means increased processing time and a more complex program.

And outputting. If column1 is to be output, then the leading space should **not** be stripped from it. Whether that extra processing is worth implementing depends on the actual situation.

It's quite possible to automatically calculate the column numbers from the names. Whether the complication that introduces is a worthwhile investment depends on the scope of the problem. If it's always going to be analysing columns 2 and 4 as described in the example narration - then probably no. If it's going to be different column combinations and possibly more than the two in the original query - then, well, it can probably be accommodated, but all at the expense of program complexity and execution time.

Then I asked "how many unique combinations are there likely to be" [What happened?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2_O4EegdNY) There's a batch technique using variable-naming that can be used. If there are a very few such combinations, then perhaps that technique could be used. It's limited - but it can also be fast. Well, fast for batch...

And all this depends on even more unstated data. Batch has a string-limit of a little over 8,000 characters. Some characters with special meaning to batch (if present) require special techniques, for instance.

And overall, the approach may not be applicable at all. I suspect the files will be too big to make this viable in the first place.