# Powershell: How to reduce my comparison time of two Arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, arraylist, comparison

I am currently rather new to PowerShell and Programming in general. I am developing a tool in PowerShell that takes two CSV files with anywhere from 5,000-40,000 lines and 30+ headers per line. The tool takes these two files and finds matching lines based on a key (Symbol) and reports the differences in the corresponding fields.

The script takes in two arguments: the two CSV files to be compared. Represented below as gcFile1 and gcFile2

These CSV files will not have the same amount of lines or all the same symbols but are listed alphabetically.

I was able to match strings based on my desired key, perform the comparison and properly output the differences.

My problem is that it takes entirely too long, my assumption is that because I'm using two ForEach loops to compare the objects it basically does this for every single line, making it take much longer than allowed.

I am looking for a way for the line to be removed from the subsequent searches once it is used to make for a smaller array to search through each time.

Thank you so much for any help :)

Here is a snippet of code that contains the ForEach loops:

```
#For each line in the first file
ForEach($line1 in $gcFile1)  
{

    #For Each line in the second file
    ForEach($line2 in $gcFile2)
    {

    #If the symbol from file one is like a symbol from file 2
    If($line1.Split(';').Get(0) -like $line2.Split(';').Get(0))
    {

        $Symbol1 = $line1.Split(';').Get(0)
        $Symbol2 = $line2.Split(';').Get(0)

        for($x=0;$x -lt $headerCount1; $x++)
        {
            If($line1.Split(';').Get($x) -like $line2.Split(';').Get($x))
            {
                $Version1 = $line1.Split(';').Get($x)
                $Version2 = $line2.Split(';').Get($x)

            } else {

                $Version1 = $line1.Split(';').Get($x)
                $Version2 = $line2.Split(';').Get($x)
                $headerName1 = $headerArray1[$x]
                $headerName2 = $headerArray2[$x]

                $bufferLength = 30 - $headerName1.Length
                $pad = " "


                for($y = 0;$y -lt $bufferLength; $y++){

                $pad += " " 

                }

                Write-Host "[$headerName1]$pad[$Version1 / $Version2]" 
                Add-Content $logfileBoth "[$headerName1]$pad[$Version1 / $Version2]"


            }
        }                                                                                                    
    } 
}
}
```

Example from the CSV:

```
Symbol;Validity;AnnualHighDate-Date;AnnualHighDate-Time;AnnualLowDate-Date;AnnualLowDate-    Time;AverageVolume100Day;AverageVolume22Day;Beta;ClosePriceMonth;ClosePriceQuarter;ClosePriceWeek;Clo sePriceYear;HighPriceCalendar;LowPriceCalendar;Mo12RateOfReturn;MovingAverage100Day;MovingAverage14Day;MovingAverage200Day;MovingAverage21Day;MovingAverage50Day;MovingAverage9Day;Volatility20Day;Volatility6Month;YTDRateOfReturn;AverageVolume250;HighDateCalendar;Size;AnnualHighDate;AnnualLowDate;CalcLastUpdate
A;valid;20140122;0;20130904;0;1.81273e+006;1.85068e+006;1.3787;57.16;57.44;57.16;57.19;61.22;51.96;0.2481;56.54;57.68;56.59;56.81;56.92;57.67;0.1804;0.1796;0.0198;2320468;20140122;248;1/22/2014;9/4/2013;9/3/2014
AA;valid;20140723;0;20130904;0;1.52891e+007;1.1017e+007;1.5202;16.61;14.89;16.61;10.63;17.22;9.82;1.2085;14.92;16.49;13.02;16.4;16.11;16.59;0.146;0.2494;0.6011;22428276;20140723;248;7/23/2014;9/4/2013;9/3/2014
```

For example I will find the Symbol A in file 1, search file 2 for Symbol A and compare the columns that correspond to the same header.

The desired result is an output with the Symbol and a list of what columns are different, with version 1 and version 2

Sample Output:

```
============================== A ==============================

[Header] [file1.txt / file2.txt]

[AverageVolume100Day]            [1.84354e+006 / 1.81273e+006]
[AverageVolume22Day]             [1.85629e+006 / 1.85068e+006]
[Beta]                           [1.5311 / 1.3787]
[Mo12RateOfReturn]               [0.2484 / 0.2481]
[MovingAverage100Day]            [56.4635 / 56.54]
[MovingAverage14Day]             [57.455 / 57.68]
[MovingAverage200Day]            [56.5412 / 56.59]
[MovingAverage21Day]             [56.7281 / 56.81]
[MovingAverage50Day]             [56.9214 / 56.92]
[MovingAverage9Day]              [57.7011 / 57.67]
[Volatility20Day]                [0.0508 / 0.1804]
[Volatility6Month]               [0.1285 / 0.1796]
[YTDRateOfReturn]                [0.02 / 0.0198]
[AverageVolume250]               [2325140 / 2320468]

============================== AA ==============================

[Header] [file1.txt / file2.txt]

[AverageVolume100Day]            [1.58983e+007 / 1.52891e+007]
[AverageVolume22Day]             [1.11858e+007 / 1.1017e+007]
[Beta]                           [1.6706 / 1.5202]
[LowPriceCalendar]               [9.825 / 9.82]
[Mo12RateOfReturn]               [1.1749 / 1.2085]
[MovingAverage100Day]            [14.8568 / 14.92]
[MovingAverage14Day]             [16.4471 / 16.49]
[MovingAverage200Day]            [12.9426 / 13.02]
[MovingAverage21Day]             [16.3967 / 16.4]
[MovingAverage50Day]             [16.0764 / 16.11]
[MovingAverage9Day]              [16.5478 / 16.59]
[Volatility20Day]                [0.0385 / 0.146]
[Volatility6Month]               [0.178 / 0.2494]
[YTDRateOfReturn]                [0.5767 / 0.6011]
[AverageVolume250]               [22544029 / 22428276]
```

Comment: Are the lines with the matching symbols also the same outside of the symbol? Is it a specific column of the csv you are matching or all columns? You might be able to utilize `compare-object` to forgo a lot of this. It would be helpful to see the content of the csvs as wel

Comment: How long is too long? ) In any case, if I were you I'd dump tables to a database and then let the DB engine do the job for me. As a free bonus you get the ability to run arbitrary SELECT without writing and debugging a whole new script every time.

Comment: I have added an example from one of the CSVs as well as some sample output of the current code. Some files can be done within 10 minutes or so which is OK. However some of these massive files can take an hour(s) or more.

Comment: `Compare-Object` might not work in this case (I said might). I know we could load the files into PowerShell and find matches between files. However loading all the data into memory might not be feasable depending on your file sizes. Are the symbols unique in files? I mean would a particular symbol only appear once in each file? Some `Import-CSV` lines and `Where-Object`s could figure this out easy. Just dont know if you will have enough memory to process. If they are unique the logic would be easy.

Comment: The symbols are unique for the immediate use. But down the line I will need some compatibility for having multiples of the same Symbol, seperated by date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least PowerShell 3.0 for this to work. Although it can be changed to support 2.0

```
$firstData = Import-CSV C:\temp\sample.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Symbol
$secondData = Import-CSV C:\temp\sample2.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Symbol

$firstData.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    If ($secondData.ContainsKey($_.Key)){
        $symbol = $_.Key

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Symbol' = $symbol
            'AverageVolume100Day' = "$($firstData[$symbol].AverageVolume100Day) / $($secondData[$symbol].AverageVolume100Day)"
            'AverageVolume22Day' = "$($firstData[$symbol].AverageVolume22Day) / $($secondData[$symbol].AverageVolume22Day)" 
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is not completly built but enough to show you what i was trying to do. You could make this so that all the parameters you are interested in are stored seperately instead of spelling the all out like I have done with `AverageVolume100Day` and `AverageVolume22Day`. Also, I do not have enough sample data to get this going

What this does is import both samples of data as `CSV`'s and converts the data into a hash table where the `Name` si the symbol and the rest of the data is the value.

Cycling through each symbol and verify if it has a match in the other sample data set. If a match is found build a custom object that has each value from each sample set of data compared with a backslash like in your data.

I ommited the Header from your output as having it repeated seemed repetative :). I have *no* idea if this will be more efficient but I would consider giving it a try.

Sample output.

```
Symbol                      AverageVolume100Day         AverageVolume22Day        
------                      -------------------         ------------------        
AA                          1.52891e+007 / 1.52891e+007 1.1017e+007 / 1.1017e+007 
A                           1.81273e+006 / 1.81573e+006 1.85068e+006 / 1.85368e...
```

The output in powershell might not be as readable and some columns might be trucated. Having this all sent to `Export-CSV` would be an option.

**Update from comments**

This is a similar solution with the added bonus of having dynamic headers. I need to work on the output a little since I'm not happy with it yet.

```
$firstData = Import-CSV C:\temp\sample.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Symbol
$secondData = Import-CSV C:\temp\sample2.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Symbol
$propertyNames = @("AverageVolume100Day","AverageVolume22Day","AnnualHighDate-Date")
$properties = @{}


$firstData.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    If ($secondData.ContainsKey($_.Key)){
        $symbol = $_.Key

        $properties.Symbol = $symbol
        ForEach($property in $propertyNames) {
            $properties.$property = "$($firstData[$symbol].$property) / $($secondData[$symbol].$property)"
        }
        New-Object Psobject -Property $properties
    }
} | Format-List
```

Use the array `$propertyNames` to fill in headers as needed. In a `ForEach-Loop` cycle through each and build the `$properties`. When you have many headers then `Format-List` will make the output readable.

Comment: I'll see if i can make something more dynamic but all you need to do is add another line for each like this `'header' = "$($firstData[$symbol].header) / $($secondData[$symbol].header)"`. If `header` contains a space just wrap it in quotes.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble taking my array of headers and adding them to the custom object, like you did manually with 'AverageVolume100Day' 'AverageVolume22Day', I'm sure my inexperience is showing here and its something simple..

Depending on the files being compared, they will all have different amounts/types of headers so being able to dynamically change them within the object would be a must.

Comment: @DavidM. Have a look at the bottom of my answer. Closer to what you want.

Comment: That's perfect. Your help is VERY appreciated! I'll get to work implementing it today.

Comment: I went ahead and made a small adjustment with an If statement to only show properties that are different and it worked wonderfully. Really I cannot thank you enough for offering your time and help (Is there such thing as Reddit Gold but for StackOverflow? :) )

The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is how to reorganize this output alphabetically by Symbol

Comment: Where i have `Format-List` you could just put `Sort-Object symbol` before it. All you need to do to show your thanks is accept the answer that you feel addressed your issue an/or upvote if you feel it was useful. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer to such a problem is to use a lookup table. There are many ways to create one. The general approach is as follows.

Calculate a hash for each data row from the first input. Store the hashes in a container. After you got the lookup table ready, read the second file row-by-row and calculate hash the same way. Check if the lookup table contains the hash. If it doesn't, you got a row that didn't exist in the first file. If it does, you got exact match.

One can calculate the hash by using, say, MD5. Store the hashes in a sorted list and use binary search to find matches in *O(n log n)*. The more simple alternative is to use hash table (aka associative array) that does hash calculations behind the curtains.

In your case, a hash of entire data row doesn't seem to be feasible. It might be more suitable to generate a lookup table that uses hash only to find the relevant row for further processing.

As for how to create a lookup table, look at [another a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059738/503046).

Comment: Thank you! This is tremendously helpful and informative